# How to make a for loop of listbox with a pause between each

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, for-loop, listbox, webbrowser-control

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim Iclick, submit

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Iclick.InvokeMember("click")
        With WebBrowser1.Document
            For l_index As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
                Dim l_text As String = CStr(ListBox1.Items(l_index))
                .All("input").InnerText = l_text
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
            Next
            '.All("input").InnerText = "http://wordpress.com"
        End With
        submit.InvokeMember("click")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://whatwpthemeisthat.com")
    End Sub

    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
        Iclick = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("input")
        submit = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("check")
    End Sub
End Class
```

This is my code so far I have a ListBox with URLs I want to check using web browser which theme are they running (if they are wordpress) but the program seems to be bugged when I click START it is NOT responding, until the last element. It has to do something with the system.threading.thread.sleep line but I don't know what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's excactly what the Thread.Sleep() method is for. It freezes for 5 seconds.
Also you are replacing the input each time the For loop repeats. So it replaces, waits 5 seconds, replaces, waits 5 sec... and so on.

I guess you are trying to click the submit button for each of the elements, but that's not what you are doing. You have to hit the submit button each time the text has changed. However you really can't be sure about the loading time of the page.

I'd suggest you to place the submit-part inside the loop, then wait, then go into the next iteration. Maybe you could even try to run the website multiple times, one for each listbox item and then apply the right text to the controls in the webpage, hit the button and receive your result.

EDIT: Your best bet for the Thread.Sleep() would be creating a new thread in which you place the loop. This thread can be paused for 5 seconds, and your application will still respond. This is how you create one:

```
    Imports System.Threading.Thread
    Dim myThread as Thread
    '//..........
    '//Button1 is clicked ->
    myThread = new Thread (AddressOf myLoop)
    myThread.start()
    '//..........
    Private Sub myLoop ()
    '// Loop goes here...
    'Sleeping here will only affect the thread that runs this sub. Your form will still be available
    End Sub
```